# Out of memory error initiating jvm

Tags: c++, excel, vba, jvm, java-native-interface

We have an OCX that functions as an SQL Query builder in Excel.  The OCX is a wrapper that runs the query builder, which is written in Java. Everything worked fine through Excel 2010.  With Excel 2013, we sometimes get an out of memory error just instantiating the jvm.  Sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't.  Here is the code to create the jvm:

```
    JavaVMInitArgs vm_args;
    JavaVMOption options[1];

    options[0].optionString = "-Djava.compiler=NONE";                               
    vm_args.version = JNI_VERSION_1_2;
    vm_args.options = options;
    vm_args.nOptions = 1;
    vm_args.ignoreUnrecognized = JNI_TRUE;

    LOG("starting JVM ");
    jint    returnCode = JNI_CreateJavaVMptr(&jvm, (void**)&env, &vm_args);
    if (returnCode < 0) 
    {
        string error = "Could not start JVM: ";
        error += getErrorMessage(returnCode);
        LOG("error starting JVM: " << error);
        throw EXCEPTION(error.c_str());
    }
    else
    {
        LOG("JVM started");
    }
```

We are using an old version of Visual Studio(2003) and Java 1.6.  Are there options we can pass to JNI_CreateJavaVMptr that would resolve the out of memory error?

Comment: How much free virtual memory is available in the process when you start it? Is it 32-bit or 64-bit?  Why are you disabling the JIT, this is normally only done to debug very speciifc problems in the JVM?

Comment: Sorry for the delay, but it took me this long to reproduce the error again after adding logging. Below are memory stats just before failure:

Comment: 2016-01-20 13:14:25.969   starting JVM 
2016-01-20 13:14:25.969  [8388] % of Memory in use:26
2016-01-20 13:14:25.969  [8388] Total KB of Physical Memory:16677860
2016-01-20 13:14:25.969  [8388] Free KB of Physical Memory:12287624
2016-01-20 13:14:25.969  [8388] Total KB of Paging File:19168228
2016-01-20 13:14:25.969  [8388] Free KB of Paging File:13251052
2016-01-20 13:14:25.969  [8388] Total KB of Virtual Memory:2097024
2016-01-20 13:14:25.969  [8388] Free KB of Virtual Memory:1455608
2016-01-20 13:14:25.976  [8388] error starting JVM: Could not start JVM: -4 JNI_ENOMEM: not enough memory

Comment: this is 32 bit Excel and ocx running on 64 bit Windows 8.1.  I'm not sure why the JIT is disabled.  I inherited this and it was there when i got it.  I will email the original developer and see if he remembers.

Comment: One other note: the memory stats for a successful run are virtually identical to the stats shown above when it failed.

Comment: @CurrieDail FYI you can click "edit" to add more details to your question, rather than pasting them (unformatted) into comments.